# manipulate output from django-export-import

Tags: python, django

I have a django app that writes the output from django-export-import, using a class, to the static folder.

I'd like to remove the first line of the output and anything after the comma.

I've tried to use re, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the current output:

`ipadd,active
192.168.42.33/32,1
192.168.95.1/32,1`

I'd like the output to be:

`192.168.42.33/32
192.168.95.1/32`

Here is my code

```
class IPResourceExport(resources.ModelResource):

class Meta:
    model = IPAddress
    fields = ('ipadd', 'active',)

def deploy_ip(request):

    queryset = IPAddress.objects.filter(active=1)
    dataset = IPResourceExport().export(queryset)

    output_path = settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/iptemp.txt'

    f = open(output_path, 'w')
    f.write(dataset.csv)
    f.flush()
    f.close()
    template_name = "block/deploy.html"
    context = {}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Updated working code:

```
def deploy_ip(request):

    queryset = IPAddress.objects.filter(active=1)
    dataset = IPResourceExport().export(queryset)

    new_data = dataset.csv
    out_data = re.sub(',1', '', new_data.split('\n', 1)[1])

    output_path = settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/output/iptemp.txt'

    f = open(output_path, 'w')
    f.write(out_data)
    f.close()
    template_name = "block/deploy.html"
    context = {}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to do the manipulation on the string object `dataset` before it gets written out to a file.

So we can start with a string

```
>>> original = "ipadd,active\n192.168.42.33/32,1\n192.168.95.1/32,1\nother stuff"
>>> print original
ipadd,active
192.168.42.33/32,1
192.168.95.1/32,1
```

And then use the string method `split` to divide the string wherever a `'\n'` occurs and return a list with all the pieces.  Since we only want to divide it in two, we will set the `maxsplit` argument to `1` [docs on str.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

```
>>> print original.split('\n', 1)
['ipadd,active', '192.168.42.33/32,1\n192.168.95.1/32,1\nother stuff']
```

Then we can use just the second piece of the list ( index 1 ) as the new string which is `dataset` with the first line removed

```
>>> print original.split('\n', 1)[1]
192.168.42.33/32,1
192.168.95.1/32,1
other stuff
```

Now for getting the `',1'` we can use the `re` module and the `sub` function to do something like a sed search and replace. We are searching for all instances of `',1'` and replacing them with `''`, aka nothing, in the target string `original.blah.blah`.
[docs on re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

```
>> import re
>>> print re.sub(',1', '', original.split('\n', 1)[1])
192.168.42.33/32
192.168.95.1/32
other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

I added regex and split to the function to get the output I needed. The code in the updated working code above works as expected. Thanks Jeb!

```
>> import re
>>> original = "ipadd,active\n192.168.42.33/32,1\n192.168.95.1/32"
>>> print original
ipadd,active
192.168.42.33/32,1
192.168.95.1/32,1
>>> print original.split('\n', 1)
['ipadd,active', '192.168.42.33/32,1\n192.168.95.1/32']
>>> print original.split('\n', 1)[1]
192.168.42.33/32,1
192.168.95.1/32,1
other stuff
>>> print re.sub(',1', '', original.split('\n', 1)[1])
192.168.42.33/32
192.168.95.1/32
>>>
```